# i have some confusion about session and cookies in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

Please read my following statements and tell me if they are true or false for persistent cookies:

1. Session and cookie are created when user logs in.
2. Session is created with a unique id which is stored in the cookie.
3. By default, a cookie stores session id only. If a developer wants, then he can store other information in that cookie with session id.
4. Session variables, if any, are removed from server memory after the session is expired or user logs out but the session id is still in the cookie.

If its true, then what is the use of session id ?

After this, user would again logs in and the cookie is replaced with a new session id. Right ?

5. After the cookie is expired, the session id is removed from cookie and the cookie is deleted.
6. For security purpose, the session must be expired before cookie. In this way, user is forced to authenticate himself and logs in to confirm its identity again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the purpose of the cookie? The server has to be able to recognize which session belongs to which client. So the SessionID is provided to the client, and communicated back and forth via cookie (or via QueryString if cookieless authentication is enabled, but that isn't recommended).

User logging in or out doesn't necessarily change the SessionID. To do that, you'd need to call `Session.Abandon()`.

Comment: Hey mason,  thank for the reply. Well, I know what a cookie is and its purpose. I just want to clear the concept and process in my mind. So, it would be helpful if you tell me whether each of the above statements are true or false. Further, u say that logging in does not affect session id, but i read that session id is created when a user log in. If not, then at which time the session id is created..?

Comment: @Piyush I don't know why you need me to tell you these things: you are capable of running a site and finding out, are you not? SessionID has nothing to do with being logged in or not. SessionID is created upon the first request to the server.

Comment: Mason, cant you say only one word for 6 statements. You dont need to explain everything,  please just answer me true or false for above statements. Further u mean, session id is same in the cookie,  even after user logs out. So, "if that user logs in again then he will be authenticated using his credentials. And the session id is useless." Right .?

Comment: @Piyush Why would SessionID be useless? It's still important for tying the session data on the server to a particular client.